# Get all rows from one table stream and the row before in time from an other table

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have one table (table_1) and one table stream (stream_1) that gets changes made to table_1, in my case only inserts of new rows. And once I have acted on these changes, the rowes will be removed from stream_1 but remain in table_1.

From that I would like to calculate delta values for var1 (var1 - lag(var1) as delta_var1) partitioned on a customer and just leave var2 as it is. So the data in table_1 could look something like this:

| timemessage | customerid | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 06:00:00 | 1 | 10 | 5 |
| 2021-04-01 07:00:00 | 2 | 100 | 7 |
| 2021-04-01 08:00:00 | 1 | 20 | 10 |
| 2021-04-01 09:00:00 | 1 | 40 | 3 |
| 2021-04-01 15:00:00 | 2 | 150 | 5 |
| 2021-04-01 23:00:00 | 1 | 50 | 6 |
| 2021-04-02 06:00:00 | 2 | 180 | 2 |
| 2021-04-02 07:00:00 | 1 | 55 | 9 |
| 2021-04-02 08:00:00 | 2 | 200 | 4 |

And the data in stream_1 that I want to act on could looks like this:

| timemessage | customerid | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 23:00:00 | 1 | 50 | 6 |
| 2021-04-02 06:00:00 | 2 | 180 | 2 |
| 2021-04-02 07:00:00 | 1 | 55 | 9 |
| 2021-04-02 08:00:00 | 2 | 200 | 4 |

But to be able to calculate delta_var1 for all customers I would need the previous row in time for each customer before the ones in stream_1.

For example: To be able to calculate how much var1 has increased for customerid = 1 between 2021-04-01 09:00:00 and 2021-04-01 23:00:00 I want to include the 2021-04-01 09:00:00 row for customerid = 1 in my output.

So I would like to create a select containing all rows in stream_1 + the previous row in time for each customerid from table_1: The wanted output is the following in regard to the mentioned table_1 and stream_1.

| timemessage | customerid | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 09:00:00 | 1 | 40 | 3 |
| 2021-04-01 15:00:00 | 2 | 150 | 5 |
| 2021-04-01 23:00:00 | 1 | 50 | 6 |
| 2021-04-02 06:00:00 | 2 | 180 | 2 |
| 2021-04-02 07:00:00 | 1 | 55 | 9 |
| 2021-04-02 08:00:00 | 2 | 200 | 4 |

Comment: the output is ambiguous , try to explain it better

Comment: I have rephrased my question a bit. Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

So given you have the "last value per day" in your wanted output, you are want a [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) to keep only the wanted rows and using [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) partitioned by `customerid` and `timemessage`. Assuming the accumulator it positive only you can order by `accumulatedvalue` thus:

```
WITH data(timemessage, customerid, accumulatedvalue) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('2021-04-01',  1,  10)
        ,('2021-04-01', 2,  100)
        ,('2021-04-02', 1,  20)
        ,('2021-04-03', 1,  40)
        ,('2021-04-03', 2,  150)
        ,('2021-04-04', 1,  50)
        ,('2021-04-04', 2,  180)
        ,('2021-04-05', 1,  55)
        ,('2021-04-05', 2,  200)
)
SELECT * FROM data
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid,timemessage ORDER BY accumulatedvalue DESC) = 1
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

gives:

```
TIMEMESSAGE CUSTOMERID  ACCUMULATEDVALUE
2021-04-01  1           10
2021-04-01  2           100
2021-04-02  1           20
2021-04-03  1           40
2021-04-03  2           150
2021-04-04  1           50
2021-04-04  2           180
2021-04-05  1           55
2021-04-05  2           200
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I do not think the solution will work, I guess my question was a bit unclear. I have rephrased it a bit now and hopefully it is more understandable. :)

Comment: @spiyugo wow, yes, your question has changed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if you can trust your data and data in table2 starts right after data in table1 then you can just get the last records for each customer from table1 and union with table2:

```
select * from table1
qualify row_number() over (partitioned by customerid order by timemessage desc) = 1
union all
select * from table2
```

if not

```
select a.* from table1 a
join table2 b
  on a.customerid = b.customerid
and a.timemessage < b.timemessage
qualify row_number() over (partitioned by a.customerid order by a.timemessage desc) = 1
union all
select * from table2
```

also you can add a condition to not look to data for more than 1 day (or 1 hour or whatever safe interval is to look at) for better performance